# Updating multiple products stock script slows over execution time

Tags: magento2.3, inventory

I'm tring to update all products of an eshop with a php script ( magento command ).
I'm preparing an array with all stock data and while looping over all shop products i'm updating the stock using the code bellow in a function

enter code here

```
   if ($isInStock === null)
        $isInStock = ($quantity > 0 ? SourceItem::STATUS_IN_STOCK : SourceItem::STATUS_OUT_OF_STOCK);

    $inventorySourceItem = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Inventory\Model\SourceItem');

    $existingInventorySourceItem = $inventorySourceItem->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('sku', $sku)
        ->addFieldToFilter('source_code', $inventorySourceCode)
        ->getFirstItem();


    $existingInventorySourceItem->setQuantity($quantity);
    $existingInventorySourceItem->setStockStatus($isInStock);
    $existingInventorySourceItem->setStatus($isInStock);
    $existingInventorySourceItem->setSku($sku);
    $existingInventorySourceItem->setSourceCode($inventorySourceCode);
    $existingInventorySourceItem->save();

    try {
        $this->objectManager->get('Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface')->execute([$existingInventorySourceItem]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The problem is tha as the loop continues, the execution of the SourceItemsSaveInterface goes slower, and the script consumes more cpu, untill it reaches 90% of cpu.

As far as i've seen in my code, everything is looking good, and the same code executes well at my development machine so i think there is something related with the server although i cant find any clue. Keep in mind that mysql doenst seem to have a hard time during the process.

Already tried to add limit to the existingInventorySourceItem query and a sleep function beetween loops

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Data needs to be from your production instance, please.

Comment: When you are ready to speed up the process completion, please post the data requested on Oct 17, 2020.